# Is it possible to create a vmware vRealize dev instalation?

Tags: automation, vmware

My company create an IPAM solution, and one of our clients asked us to develop a vRO workflow to provision IPs through vRealize Automation. I'm searching online on how to set a development environment, and all the resources I saw state that you need a vRO installation to develop the plugin itself, it is not enough to have VSC with the vRealize Dev Tools installed. I tried searching for an SDK or just a small vRO installation to use for dev, but only thing I saw on the vmware website was the hands-on lab or the 60 days trial of vSphere, whose links no longer work at all.

Do I need to buy a vRealize Orchestrator license just to develop the plugin?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to procure the vRA license to develop the Workflow in vRO; or, you can reach out to vmware: if they agree to your team being a partner, then you will get NOT FOR SALE/Trial license for vRA.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need vRealize Orchestrator license to develop a vRO plugin.
vRO plugin is not the same thing as vRO workflow.

vRO plugin:
[image]

vRO workflow:
[image]

[What you mentioned can be done using vRealize Automation REST API.](https://code.vmware.com/apis/165/vra-ipam)